# Windows CE (RTOS) class-libraries for latency of interrupts and threads and USB?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce

I am getting started in working with Windows CE to utilize RTOS to reduce latency concerns with interrupts and threads and USB.  What class-libraries(visual c++) can you point me to that would be good to have learned well to speed up the learning curve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really, really broad question.  The most important piece of advice I'll give you is that if you're after determinism and speed (your reference to an RTOS leads me to think you consider these important) then you need to be aware that any memory allocation or deallocation in a piece of code makes it non-deterministic.

C++ classes often have allocations and deallocations buried in them, so whatever you choose (and whatever you write), use them wisely.  Sometimes they'll allow you to provide custom allocators (e.g. Boost) which you can use to just pull memory from an already allocated heap you create somewhere.

Keep the real-time parts of the code as small and simple as possible.

Comment: The methods will be on the heap for each class, however the methods of criticality: (latency concerns), will be methods written in standard-c with no inheritance. I guess the question is, when I instantiate a class, could things run different on each time for methods written in standard-c?  The only thing I see as a main concern is a block of memory that is not continuous and the jumping around could increase or at least make the latency different on each run.  But won't the assembler catch this and prevent this?

Comment: A method written in C or C++ that doesn't make any memory allocations or deallocations (and, obviously, makes no Wait calls) is going to be deterministic *provided* you have your thread priorities set up to prevent the scheduler from context-switching you out.  Memory fragmentation is not going to cause and read/write latency issues, only allocation speed changes.